# Editing values in a pandas dataframe using data from another part of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I was hoping to use indexing on one part of a Pandas DataFrame to edit values
corresponding to another index. Here is an example:

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> from numpy.random import randn
>>> x = DataFrame(randn(3, 3), columns=[1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> print x

        1         2         3
a -1.007344  0.234990  0.772736
b  0.658360  1.330051 -0.269388
c  0.010871  1.035687  0.230169


>>> index1 = x.index[0:2]
>>> index2 = x.index[1:3]
>>> y = x
>>> x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index2, 2]
>>> print x


        1         2         3
a -1.007344  0.234990       NaN
b  0.658360  1.330051  1.330051
c  0.010871  1.035687  0.230169
```

Where the latter output is rather unexpected. What does work instead is the following:

```
>>> y.loc[index1, 3] = y.loc[index2, 2].values
>>> print y

       1         2         3
a -1.007344  0.234990  1.330051
b  0.658360  1.330051  1.035687
c  0.010871  1.035687  0.230169
```

However, this latter solution is inconvenient for a number of applications I would like to use. For example, I would like to write:

```
x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index2, 2]+2
```

or

```
x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index1, 3] + x.loc[index2, 2]
```

etc.

Is there another way around this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas is great for aligning based on index. The "unexpected" result is actually understandable if you think of

```
x.loc[index1, 3]
```

as a Series with index labels `['a', 'b']` and assignment

```
x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index2, 2]
```

is assigning new values from `x.loc[index2, 2]` which is a Series with index labels `['b', 'c']`. Since the data on the right-hand side only *aligns* with the Series on the left at the label `'b'`, that label gets a new value, while the label `a` is set to `NaN`, since the right-hand side has no value for that index.

When you want Pandas to disregard the index, you need to pass an object on the right-hand side that has no index. So, as you showed,

```
y.loc[index1, 3] = y.loc[index2, 2].values
```

produces the desired result.

Similarly, for your more complicated assignments, you could use

```
x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index2, 2].values + 2
```

or

```
x.loc[index1, 3] += x.loc[index2, 2].values
```

(Note the second assignment uses the in-place addition operator, `+=`.)

If you have a lot of assignments that ignores the index, then perhaps you should be using a NumPy array instead of a Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3, 3)), columns=[1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
arr = x.values
print(arr)
# [[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]
#  [6 7 8]]

index1 = slice(0,2)
index2 = slice(1,3)
arr[index1, 2] = arr[index2, 1]
print(arr)
# [[0 1 4]
#  [3 4 7]
#  [6 7 8]]

# Instead of x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index2, 2]+2 
arr[index1, 2] = arr[index2, 1] + 2
print(arr)
# [[0 1 6]
#  [3 4 9]
#  [6 7 8]]

# Instead of x.loc[index1, 3] = x.loc[index1, 3] + x.loc[index2, 2]
arr[index1, 2] += arr[index2, 1]
print(arr)
# [[ 0  1 10]
#  [ 3  4 16]
#  [ 6  7  8]]

x.loc[:,:] = arr
print(x)
#    1  2   3
# a  0  1  10
# b  3  4  16
# c  6  7   8
```